# Linear State space model for mobile robot

Tags: mobile-robot, line-following

How can I write a linear state space model for a 4 wheel mobile robot with Ackerman steering in terms of error. I want the robot to follow a line. The robot is rear wheel drive

Answer (score 3):

Read and understand [this](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node658.html). Refer to other sections of that site, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not exactly what you wanted, but you should look into the [Pure Pursuit](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/coulter_r_craig_1992_1/coulter_r_craig_1992_1.pdf) algorithm for line following.